# Is it possible to change 0000000,00 to 0000000.00 with maual formulas or vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a data set with values to export from excel to file txt and therefore, they need to have specific formatting, such as the column of values (as explained below).

My columns are: Year | Month | Company | Number | Value | Note

At the column "Value" I have this format (custom): 0000000,00;-0000000,00

I would like to change comma to dot in order to have this aspect: 0000000.00.

In the table I have, for example: 0000015,70 and I would like to change for 0000015.70

Is it possible to change through manual formulas or vba code?
[image]

Comment: Is comma your decimal seperator? If yes, and you change it to dot they are no numbers anymore and you can't calculate with them. But you can change that for the entire workbook: See [Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

Comment: Well, it's a stretch but through formulae you can add a column based on your values `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(E2,"0000000,00"),",",".")` and if at any point you'd want to work with these numbers, either refer to your column E (that you might want to hide? Or use `=NUMBERVALUE(<Reference>,".")`.

Comment: You can look onto your regional settings as well, changing the present decimal symbol from , to . can easily workout.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your custom format to 0000000.00;-0000000.00 and then SaveAs TXT, EXCEL writes that column in that format.

It is also possible to have those values repeated in a new column, but with the desired format, by using a formula LIKE =text(E2, "0000000.00").